# Allowing reference lifetime to outlive a closure

Tags: rust

I'm getting to grips with Rust by trying to implement a singly-linked list.  Here are my data structures:

```
struct Linked<T> {
    head: Option<Box<Node<T>>>
}

struct Node<T> {
    data: T,
    next: Option<Box<Node<T>>>
}
```

Now, I'd like to add an iterator to this:

```
struct LinkedIter<'a, T: 'a> {
    node: Option<&'a Node<T>>,
}
```

I've written a `.iter()` method for `Linked<T>`, which compiles and works fine.

```
impl<T> Linked<T> {
    fn iter(&self) -> LinkedIter<T> {
        LinkedIter { node: match self.head {
                Some(ref node) => Some(&**node),
                None           => None
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, this `match` block is converting an `Option<Box<Linked<T>>>` to an `Option<&Linked<T>>`.  This is exactly what the `Option::map()` method is for.  So I reimplemented this method, using `head.as_ref()` instead of `head` to avoid taking ownership of the `Option`'s contents in the closure.

```
impl<T> Linked<T> {
    fn iter(&self) -> LinkedIter<T> {
        LinkedIter { node:
            self.head.as_ref().map(|b: &Box<Node<T>>| &**b)
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the reference created in the closure cannot be allowed to outlive the closure, because it refers to something passed into the closure as a parameter.  The compiler complains (paraphrased a bit):

> error: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for borrow expression due to conflicting requirements:
>
> first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined [in the closure]
>
> but, the lifetime must be valid for [the lifetime of the `iter` function]
>
> so that the [`node:`] expression is assignable

How can I explain to the compiler that the reference will still be valid after the closure ends?

[(Playground)](http://is.gd/laiDuZ)

Comment: I'm setting up a minimal example on the Rust Playground. Your code does fail to compile, but not the way you describe it to (at least, that's not the first error coming up). Anyway, here's the link, it should provide a good starting point to solve your specific problem: http://is.gd/HleNDJ

Comment: And here is the minimal example which does trigger your error: http://is.gd/laiDuZ

Comment: Whoops, I took the lifetime specifiers out of the code when I moved it to SO, forgetting that they were necessary.  Lemme add those back, thanks.  The second one does indeed fail the way I'm asking about.  Thanks for the MWE link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is to inform the compiler that the reference you're taking in `map()` lives as long as the iterator. I got it working like that:

```
impl<T> Linked<T> {
    fn iter<'a>(&'a self) -> LinkedIter<T> {
        LinkedIter { node:
            self.head.as_ref().map(|b: &'a Box<Node<T>>| &**b)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Gotcha. Is it really valid to say that the reference may live as long as the Linked (which is `self` in this method)? For example, might the Node owned by the `head` be deleted, invalidating the iterator?

Comment: This won't be possible, because if you hold an iterator `LinkedIter`, it means you've borrowed a piece of the owner `Linked` (or `head`, as you mention) to populate it. Therefore, the borrow checker would reject any attempt to modify the `Linked` until you release the `LinkedIter`.

Comment: Gotcha. That makes sense.